# Submit a form with a button (HTML)

Tags: html, forms, submit

I am making a program that would post on a webpage, to submit the form it has to "click" on a button:

```
<button class="form" type="submit">Send</button>
```

From what I know (not much) to submit a POST request when it's INPUT you must do *name=value*, but I don't know how I could do that with a submit button.

Basically I want to know what I must POST to the website so that it submits the form :p

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's basic syntax for a form:

```
<form>
  <input name="name" type="text"/>
  <button type="submit"> Send </button>
</form>
```

Whatever backend you are using should be able to read POST request parameter "name" to read what that form contains.

If you're trying to make a form with just that one button, you can do that by just skipping that `input` element. Of course, there will be no data in that post request, but you can add the `action` attribute to the containing form and set it equal to a URL where you would like to redirect the user on button click.

Comment: This form will *not* `POST` data as there is no `method` attribute - the default method used by forms is `GET` so the comment `Whatever backend you are using should be able to read POST request parameter "name"` is incorrect.